# Mocking decorator with that uses hardcoded global variable

Tags: python, unit-testing

When trying to unittest the below seen code snippet i get limited by the timing limit that the decorator that wraps `calc_something` functions puts to me. It seems that I cant override `RAND_RATE` on my unittests since then I import the module containing my implementation the  decorators have already wrapped my function. How can I solve that issue?

```
RAND_RATE=20
RAND_PERIOD=10

@limits(calls=RAND_RATE, period=RAND_PERIOD)
def calc_something():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what `limits` does, we don't know what (if anything) can be patched. Instead, leave the base implementation *undecorated* for use by unit test. `calc_something` will be saved as the separate result of applying `limits` manually.

```
RAND_RATE=20
RAND_PERIOD=10

def _do_calc():
    ...


calc_something = limits(calls=RAND_RATE, period=RAND_PERIOD)(_do_calc)
@limits(calls=RAND_RATE, period=RAND_PERIOD)
def calc_something():
    ...
```

Now in your tests, you can define any decorated version you like:

```
test_me = limits(10, 5)(my_module._do_calc)
```